# How to attach a ajax response to a variable using only vanilla ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, response, constants

Let's consider we have a file named **hello.txt**, and its content is :

> Hello World !

We have a constant **res**, which is defined as :

```
const res = AJAXResponse("hello.txt")
```

So, far I defined **AJAXResponse()** as :

```
const AJAXResponse = (src) => {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', src, true);

  request.onload = function() {
  if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var resp = this.response;
  } else {
   // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
  }
}

request.onerror = function() {
 // There was a connection error of some sort
}

request.send()

}
```

This works preety fine but I am not able to attach the data in **this.response** to the **res** constant. I want the output to be something like this :

```
const res = "Hello World !" // As returned by the function
```

But, I don't know how to do it. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Due to javascript nature, you can't, unless you use `async`

Comment: @ariel So, if I replace the boolean true with false, and make the call sync..., then will it work ?

Comment: Maybe, but you shouldn't. I was talking about `async`/`await` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function